# Placing a value in a parameter in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to figure it out what is the purpose of `match` in this function?. I try to remove it and the result is

> NaN 1, NaN 2, and NaN 101

```js
var stock = "1 lemon, 2 cabbages, and 101 eggs";
function minusOne(amount, unit) {
  amount = Number(amount) - 1;
  if (amount == 1) // only one left, remove the 's'
    unit = unit.slice(0, unit.length - 1);
  else if (amount == 0)
    amount = "no";
  return amount + " " + unit;
}
console.log(stock.replace(/(\d+) (\w+)/g, minusOne));
```

---

**Output of the givin code below**

> no lemon, 1 cabbage, and 100 eggs

```js
var stock = "1 lemon, 2 cabbages, and 101 eggs";

function minusOne(match, amount, unit) {
  amount = Number(amount) - 1;
  if (amount == 1) // only one left, remove the 's'
    unit = unit.slice(0, unit.length - 1);
  else if (amount == 0)
    amount = "no";
  return amount + " " + unit;
}
console.log(stock.replace(/(\d+) (\w+)/g, minusOne));
```

**[Code Reference](http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html)**

Comment: why you are minus your amount? please see the code below..
amount = Number(amount) - 1;

Comment: @RanaGhosh I am just reading a blog. Sorry I don't about what he means in that code. I include the reference.

Comment: The `minusOne` function is being used by `replace` as a callback. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Also, `replace` uses regular expression under the hood, so `match` is the regex matches found in the `stock` string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `String.prototype.replace()` function takes an optional function parameter [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

It is just because it's the built-in behavior of the function, if you remove the `match` it will replace `match` with `amount` (in your case). It just simply doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), you will find that is the first parameter of the callback function of `replace`.